# restricted maps

Tags: math-mode

I want to write a 'restricted map' (a map which is equal to another map but with a smaller domain), we show it by drawing a vertical line and a subscript but I don't know if it has a specific method when we use TeX, the method I used so far is

```
$f|_P:A\longrightarrow B$
```

or

```
$\nu|_P:A\longrightarrow B$
```

Which doesn't have a very beautiful result. If anyone knows the standard method of writing restricted maps I will be thankful to hear it.

Comment: This is a commonly used method; you should do `\newcommand{\restr}[1]{|_{#1}}` and use `$f\restr{P}\colon A\rightarrow B$`, so you're free to change the realization of the restriction symbol without chasing for it in the document. Note that `\rightarrow` is usually better than `\longrightarrow`: less space and same meaning.

Comment: And please observe, that  instead of `:` should be  `\colon`, as in egreg's comment.

Comment: I'm with @egreg on this one, though I'd name it something like `\RestrictedTo` or `\RestrictTo`, yes more typing, but yoiu (and coauthors) will know what it means when you come back to the manuscript after a few months.

Comment: Thank you @egreg, PrzemystawScherwentke and daleif. So the standard method is same as what I used but can't I make it looks better, for example the above of the vertical line start from top of the $\nu$ or $f$ and not higher than it and the subscript looks smaller. By the way thank you for informing me about other standard rules as well. egreg please write your comment as an answer. ^_^